# Find and replace all occurrence of a function definition

Tags: visual-studio, notepad++

I want to delete all occurrences of a function definition.

I have a lot of member functions with the same prototype overloaded in multiple derived classes
For example,

```
void **********::func()
{
.
..
...
}
```

The above function definition are different in number of lines in each occurrence.

Is there a way to do this in visual studio? If not in notepad++ or some other editor?

Comment: You'll need a good regex for this, and in the end you'll have to verify the result anyway. it's easier to use class view and search for function name, then delete by jumping from one to another.

Comment: Thanks. I finally used regex to do in 2 steps in notepad++. I have 217 classes in total derived of a base class. So manually going through it in class view is out of question.